# angular 4 - read dynamicly array from firebase

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase

I'm creating reviews for products in my shop. My problem is I have button and click event to save the review on db, and later I want to read those reviews and count rating for that product. My function averageRate is not working well, I figured out that when I want to read my all reviews and map rate values I'm not getting the last one which I added, How to fix this?

**When reviews is not created on product object**

When i click button to add review on product that has not any reviews, i have no errors but it's not showing dynamicly to list on component.html (i must reload)

**When is at least one review**

When i click review is added dynamicly to list of reviews but average and array of rating are not uploaded, i don't know how to do this.

```
export class ProductReviewsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input("product") product: Product;
  currentRate = 0; // display selected stars
  review = {};
  reviews = {};
  description: string; 
  product$; 
  userSubscription: Subscription;
  appUser: AppUser;
  key: any[] = []; // review array of object
  ratingTotal;
  items: number; // length
  sum: number; // sum
  average = 0;
  rates;

  constructor(
    config: NgbRatingConfig,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private reviewService: ReviewsService
  ) {
    config.max = 5;
    this.auth.appUser$.subscribe(appUser => (this.appUser = appUser));
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    if(this.product.reviews) {

     this.product$ = await this.reviewService.getReview(this.product.$key); // display reviews
     this.key = Object.values(this.product.reviews ? this.product.reviews : []) // get array of reviews object
     this.items = this.key.length; 
     this.rates = this.key.map(item => item.rate); // get rate array of $values
     this.sum = this.rates.reduce(this.total); // sum rates 
     this.average = this.averageRating(); // count average
    }

  }

  averageRating() {
    return this.sum / this.items;
  }

  private total(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  // button click event
  addReview() {
    let review = {
      rate: this.currentRate,
      description: this.review
    };

    // I want after click to update array of reviews and count new average

    this.reviewService.saveReview(this.product.$key, review); // 

  /*  from review.service method to save review on db
    saveReview(id, review) {
    return this.db.list("/products/" + id + '/reviews/').push(review);
 } */

  }
}
```

component.html

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <ng-template #t let-fill="fill">
      <span *ngIf="fill === 100" class="star full">&hearts;</span>
      <span *ngIf="fill === 0" class="star">&hearts;</span>
      <span *ngIf="fill < 100 && fill > 0" class="star">
        <span class="half" [style.width.%]="fill">&hearts;</span>&hearts;
      </span>
    </ng-template>

    <ngb-rating [(rate)]="currentRate" [starTemplate]="t" [readonly]="false" max="5"></ngb-rating>


    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea #item #description="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="review.description" name="description" maxlength="255" type="text" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Dodaj opis..." required></textarea>
      <span>Zostało {{255 - item.value.length}} znaków</span>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="description.touched && description.invalid">
        <div *ngIf="description.errors.required">Name is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button (click)="addReview()" [disabled]="!appUser || currentRate === 0" class="btn btn-primary">Dodaj opinię</button>
  <ng-container *ngIf="items > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let review of product$ | async">
      <ngb-rating [(rate)]="review.rate" [readonly]="true"></ngb-rating> {{review.rate}}

      <p>{{ review.description.description }}</p>

    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <button *ngIf="items > 3">load more</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix that, and it's working so good

i added ngOnChanges implemetation and eureka!

```
ngOnChanges() {
    if(this.product.reviews) {
      this.product$ = this.reviewService.getReview(this.product.$key);
      this.key = Object.values(this.product.reviews ? this.product.reviews : [])
      this.items = this.key.length;
      this.rates = this.key.map(item => item.rate);
      this.sum = this.rates.reduce(this.total);
      this.average = this.averageRating();
     }
  }
```