# Dynamically subscribe to firebase observable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire2

I have an array of strings that are also keys for endpoints in my Firebase Realtime Database. I would like to loop through this array and get the Firebase object for each one of the keys.

I get no response with the code below

Is there a way to dynamically subscribe to Firebase Observables?

```
sortedArray:any = ["x","y","z"]
```

The method :

```
  getItems() {
        this.sortedArray.forEach(el => {
          this.ngDB.object(`items/${el}`).valueChanges()
          .toPromise().then((res) => {
            console.log("Found Item",res);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("Err listing items", err);
          })          
        });
  }
```

Comment: this.ngDB.object is returning an Observable ?

Comment: @Luillyfe yes it returns and Obdervable that I convert to a promise with the toPromise() methos

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325904/angular-4-read-dynamicly-array-from-firebase i used here array from firebase and each step is described to pick only one record from each key value pair, i think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to here: `.toPromise().then((res) => {` when you change from **Observable** to a **Promise**, that code is no longer keeping track of the changes. Just keep using your Observable and subscribe.

```
getItems() {
    this.sortedArray.forEach(el => {
        this.ngDB.object(`items/${el}`)
        .valueChanges()
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log("Found Item",res);
        }, err => {
            console.log("Err listing items", err);
        })          
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd stick with Observables in Angular. Ultimately, the answer here depends on how you need to "flatten" them.

Simplistically, you could combine the latest results of all the `valueChanges`

```
getItems() {
  Observable.withLatestFrom(
    this.sortedArray
      .map { id => this.ngDB.object(`items/${id}`).valueChanges() }
  )
}
```

But this has several anti-patterns; namely you have a "getter" for an observable. Unlike a Promise an Observable is lazy out-of-the-box, so there's no need to wrap with a function.
Further, a getter function is just asking for trouble because you could get surprising results if it is called more than once and how do you dispose all the subscriptions? You're not tracking them.

A better pattern would be to set items (or `items$` is you use finnish notation) as an attribute. But what if you change `sortedArray`? You'll need to dispose of the existing subscriptions and alter the Observables... if we change `sortedArray` to an `Observable` (or a `BehaviorSubject` if you need easy interop with non-Rx) we get all this for "free" with a `switchMap`:

```
this.items = this.sortedArray.switchMap(ids =>
  Observable.combineLatest(
    ids.map { id => this.ngDB.object(`items/${id}`).valueChanges() }
  }
}
```

Then use the `async` pipe in your view, use RxJS operators to mix and match it with other observables, or call `.subscribe` to get the value over time.